# Which database is best suitable to track users activity on website to know user interest

Tags: database, push-notification, personalization

I want to build a system there I will store user all activity and group user to the segments based on their interest

Answer (score 0):

It depents in how you will read data and how much of the work you want to do on database server or with your own application.

We use monitoring and logging with Elastic Search and have a separate service which handles logging messages posted to rabbitmq. A second service handles statistic messages and Stores it into a SQL Database so our web application can read it in realtime and Show some charts which are implemented in our backend system.

Just use the Repository/Service pattern with the use of a generic Repository and you can easy Switch your Database If you want after it dont fits your needs.